# Spring AuthenticationFilter triggered although URI is set to permitAll

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-rest

I try to secure access to SpringBoot REST services via a Bearer Token. I followed: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-api-key-secret

Although I set a URL "api/v1/security/auth/login" to permitAll, still the AuthenticationSecurity Filter is triggered.

My Config:

```
@Log4j2
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class AuthenticationRESTControllerSecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        log.traceEntry("securityFilterChain is build");

        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("api/v1/security/auth/login").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .sessionManagement(httpSecuritySessionManagementConfigurer -> httpSecuritySessionManagementConfigurer.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER))
                .addFilterBefore(new AuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        log.traceEntry("securityFilterChain build completed");
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

The authentication filter:

```
public class AuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        log.traceEntry();
        try {
            Authentication authentication = AuthenticationService.getAuthentication((HttpServletRequest) request);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            log.debug("API Key Authentication failed with: {}", exp.getMessage());
            HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            httpResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            httpResponse.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
            PrintWriter writer = httpResponse.getWriter();
            writer.print(exp.getMessage());
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        } finally {
            log.traceExit();
        }
    }
}
```

I expected that `.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests.requestMatchers("api/v1/security/auth/login").permitAll()` from the Config would cause spring to omit the Authentication Filter. I can not see why it is called and Authentication is attempted.